# When joining a channel using Laravel Echo, how do I tell when authentication fails?

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

When I'm joining a channel using `Echo.channel(channelName)` or `Echo.join(channelName)` or `Echo.private(channelName)`, followed by `.listen()`, how do I tell if the authentication failed on the server side? It seems like all of the above functions return a js object that, for all intents and purposes, looks like it is connected, even when it's not. For example:

```
var obj = Echo.channel('some-channel-that-always-fails-authentication');
```

Here, `.channel()` returns a `SocketIoPresenceChannel` where `obj.socket.connected` is true. Meanwhile, the server is reporting that the user "could not be authenticated to some-channel-that-always-fails-authentication" which is what I am expecting because I am deliberately returning false in my channel definition in `routes/channels.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `connect_error` event on the connector to catch any connection errors.

For example:

```js
Echo.connector.socket.on('connect_error', function (error) {
    // Handle the error
});
```

Then when you join a channel:

```js
Echo.private('some-channel-that-always-fails-authentication');
```

It will trigger the handle callback.

For [more information about events](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect-error%E2%80%99-1)

Comment: Hm, I think you may have meant either `Echo.channel('some-channel-that-always-fails-authentication').socket.on('connect_error', function(error) { ... });` (note the `.socket` part) or `Echo.channel('some-channel-that-always-fails-authentication').listen('connect_error', function(error) { ... });` since Echo uses `.listen()` whereas socket.io uses `.on()`.  Either way, it still doesn't seem to be calling that function when it fails to authenticate...

Comment: @fronzee Have a look at my update. Just tested it on my local machine and it should be working. Bind the event on the connector instead.

Comment: The event is binding properly but it still seems as if an authentication error just isn't triggering the `connect_error`